# Trouble with out parameter

Tags: c#, .net

I'm having problems with calling a method that I have made.

The method I'm calling to is as folows

```
public bool GetValue(string column, out object result)
{
    result = null;
    // values is a Dictionary<string, object>
    if (this._values.ContainsKey(column))
    {
        result = Convert.ChangeType(this._values[column], result.GetType());
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I'm caling the method with the this code but I get an compiler error

```
int age;
a.GetValue("age", out age as object)
```

> A ref or out argument must be an assignable variable

Does anyone else had this problem or am I just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The variable needs to be exatly of the type specified in the method signature. You can't cast it in the call.

The expression `age as object` is not an assignable value because it is an expression, not a storage location. For example, you cannot use it on the left hand of an assignment:

```
age as object = 5; // error
```

If you want to avoid casting, you could try using a generic method:

```
public bool GetValue<T>(string column, out T result)
{
    result = default(T);
    // values is a Dictionary<string, object>
    if (this._values.ContainsKey(column))
    {
        result = (T)Convert.ChangeType(this._values[column], typeof(T));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Of course, some error checking should be inserted where appropriate)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
public bool GetValue<T>(string column, out T result)
{
    result = default(T);
    // values is a Dictionary<string, object>
    if (this._values.ContainsKey(column))
    {
        result = (T)Convert.ChangeType(this._values[column], typeof(T));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

example invoke

```
int age;
a.GetValue<int>("age", out age);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
object age; 
a.GetValue("age", out age);

int iage = (int)age;
```

Comment: You shouldn't use hungarian notation. Better names would be `object tmp` and `int age`.

Comment: @Justin I wanted to get the real type (int/string/bool/enz) without having to cast the type